# Get a email with visitors IP when he visits my website

Tags: php, html, email

I want to receive an email when a user visits my website. Also I want the email to contain the IP address of the visitor.

I understand the basics of php but not sure how to make such a script in it.
Even if you could show me a direction where I can get such a script will do.

If I am framing the question wrong please correct me.

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives you users ip, use php mail() function to send email, thats a direction

Comment: Why put such a load (assuming that you have a popular web site) on your email/web server. Why not just use a log file?

Comment: @EdHeal : Well the purpose of the website is different and its not so popular as well.

Comment: @AleksandarVasić : Thanks but can you provide more details about the script :)

Comment: Anyway you cannot infer much from the IP address. They are shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written the script for you. But remember: this is the **wrong** solution. There are many security problems.

If an attacker loads this script multiple times, a huge load will be generated on your server. You should log visitors to a logfile or a database.

```
<?php

// set your e-mail address first, where you'll receive the notifications
$yourEmailAddress = "user@domain.com";

$emailSubject = "New Visitor on Webpage";
$remoteIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$emailContent = "Someone visited your webpage. IP address:".$remoteIpAddress;

// send the message
mail($yourEmailAddress, $emailSubject, $emailContent);

?>
```

Comment: Also remember that the whole thing won't work if your website is hosted behind a proxy, like the CloudFlare service or a load balancer. You'll just see the IP of the proxy, and not the visitor's one.